# The Jupyter env in PyCharm is unable to render pythreejs 3D models！

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.8, 3d-model, pythreejs

I tried running code in **Jupyter within PyCharm**, as shown in Figure 1. The code is expected to draw a 3D box model, but nothing is output. After checking, there are no bugs. So, I opened the web **version of Jupyter **as shown in Figure 2. The same code got the result I wanted. What is the reason for this difference?[fig 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gHCw.png)[fig 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yneFK.png)

```
from pythreejs import * # pythreejs-V:2.4.2
from IPython.display import display
from math import pi
#%%
# Reduce repo churn for examples with embedded state:
from pythreejs._example_helper import use_example_model_ids
use_example_model_ids()
#%%
BoxGeometry(
    width=5,
    height=10,
    depth=15,
    widthSegments=5,
    heightSegments=10,
    
    depthSegments=15)
```

Actually, I find it more comfortable and convenient to write code in PyCharm, and I hope that Jupyter in PyCharm can render 3D models.